# android jetpack paging for multiple child recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack

There is a parent recyclreview. The number of items is dynamic and I am receiving it from server. Each item contains list of items(child items). I am using recyclreview to show items. initially we show few items in each child and as user scroll horizontal, we load more items. It is similar like google playstore app home screen. I know I can do it making each child infinite scroll recyclerview, make network call when user reach end and then update that child. Can I do the same using paging library like using pagedkeydatasource so that I don't have to observe recyclerview scroll and make network call depending on condition but paging library manage that for me. Or do you think there is any better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

yes, the paging library is the best solution so far and choose paging DataSource wisely depending upon your server response and make sure your server response is supporting paging.

Comment: how can i do it using paging library.